# Swipe button doesn't show at cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UIViewController with `tableView` and custom cell. I want to add swipe delete button to cell. When i used `UITableViewController` and define `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath` swipe button works well. But now it doesn't appear. Swipe action is working, but button is not appear. What i'm doing wrong ?

```
    class CartViewController: UIViewController,  UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
        @IBOutlet weak var tableView:UITableView!

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            ...
            return items_count
        }
        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 

              ...
        }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
        let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "Delete",handler: { (action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> Void in
                ...
            })
        return [deleteAction]
    }


}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you have the extra comma in your returned array?